# Meaning of babel error: "Complex binding patterns require an initialization value"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm using linting my reactjs code with babel and am running into this strangely tough to track down issue:

`"Parsing Error: Complex binding patterns require an initialization value"`

For this line of my react code: 

`var {children={}, Activator={}} = this.props`

Does anyone know what this means or how to make it go away?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I think it is the babel parsing that is failing. Not really related to eslint, it showed up through my linter though which I usually associate with eslint.

Comment: Which version of Babel are You using?

Answer (score 3):

The last time I encountered this issue, it was due to some improper destructuring syntax. Your issue might be related to a difficulty in parsing the destructuring in your variable assignment.